# Selenium checking if tab is open

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to check if a url is open in a tab, and if it is, print `found`. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

tabs_list = []
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    tabs_list.append(driver.current_url)

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
for tab in tabs_list:
    if url in tab:
        print('found')
```

When I run this, nothing happens for several seconds, then a new Firefox window is opened, with an [orange search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mOTW.png). `found` also is not printed, even though `google.com` is running. When I print my tabs_list to see what is inside, I get `['about:blank']`.

On further testing I discovered that it was searching for tabs in the new window. Is there any way to make it search through an existing window, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: did you get the url first, like driver.get('https://google.com') ??

Comment: Yes, I did test that, but it opened it in the new window, and I want to check an existing window, not a new one.

Comment: when you start driver and get to the new window it will not open new tab, just move existing one

Comment: Well for me it opens the tab in the `get()` in the new window and then searches through the new window instead of the one that was already open.

Comment: hm, it works only with the current one usually

Comment: @Vova Do you know why the search bar is orange? is it safe mode or something?

Comment: yes, it's due to typo, like url inside quotes and other quotes)
driver.get('"http://www.google.com/"')

Comment: your code is working corrctly i am able to see found printed ,

Comment: @PDHide does it open a new window for you?

Comment: It opens only one window and tab , you are not opening more than one in your script . What are you trying to do

Comment: @PDHide I have an open Firefox window, before I run the code. I want to code to check the window to see if a certain tab is open. But instead of checking the first one, it opens a different window and checks that one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, you're using url in quotes in other quotes, like:

```
driver.get('"http://www.google.com/"')
```

so that one should work perfectly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```